# How map/forward port under Ubuntu for other machine ? (localhost 555 -> 192.168.0.21:555)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port, forwarding

Any idea how I can create a "virtual" listening port on my Ubuntu computer porting for remote IP?

I mean, something like this.

When I write *telnet 127.0.0.1 555*, I want to get a connection to computer *192.168.0.21* on port *555* (where I have my server).

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I think [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) is what you're looking for and it should already be installed with Ubuntu.

It may take a bit of trial and error but something like the commands below should do the trick:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 555 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.21:555
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 555 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

A more detailed explanation of what these commands do can be found [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/73).

Another method is to use a program called [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) which is available in Ubuntu via synaptic.

> Redirects TCP connections from one IP
>   address and port to another. rinetd is
>   a single-process server which handles
>   any number of connections to the
>   address/port pairs specified in the
>   file /etc/rinetd.conf.

There's a nice guide on how to use it [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Easily_forwarding_arbitrary_TCP_connections_with_rinetd)

Comment: But it won't bind local port. I'm looking for "port tunneling"

I don't want access that port from LAN but from local machine.

On computer where i want forward it, i want say  telnet localhost 555 and it should connect me to remote computer called 192.168.0.21.

On windows it's called port tunell.


http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=18

Comment: I would have thought IP tables would work by telneting 127.0.0.1:55 but you could also try a program called rinetd which can redirect ports too.  I've added details to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4033.html

> You think this should be enough by now, and it really is, unless considering one final aspect to this whole scenario. What if the firewall itself tries to access the HTTP  server, where will it go? As it looks now, it will unfortunately try to get to its own HTTP server, and not the server residing on $HTTP_IP. To get around this, we need to add a DNAT rule in the OUTPUT  chain as well. Following the above example, this should look something like the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst $INET_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $HTTP_IP
```

Answer (score 1):

Use redir instead of iptables: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/redir.1.html